# getting unspecified error while compiling a WP7 program

Tags: windows-phone-7

im receiving a very weird error from the IDE while compiling.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for
>   Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Phone.PreImport.targets(38,9): error : Could not
>   load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

what really makes this weird is the fact that on another computer the program is compilable.

thanks for your help

edit: just found out that the reason for that error is because of the panorama -view.. i tried to create a new project with a panorama view, still received same error

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the latest wp7 sdk?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the correct references in the project?
2. Did you modify any of the "stock" references?

You could try repairing the SDK or create a new Panorama-based application and see if it works.

Comment: i've not touched any of the references, im currntly running a fresh installation of the SDK on my laptop, hopefuly that will solve the problem, i will let you know